Getting random symbols after trying to replace chars in C++
I'm trying to replace every letter in string to next letter (a -> b, c -> d, etc.).
I get random symbols or XXXX after compiling and running the program.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    char arr1[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                       'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                       'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                       'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                       'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                       'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                       'y', 'z'};
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
        for(int h = 0; h < 26; h++){
            if(x[i] == arr1[h]){
                x[i] = arr1[h + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}

I think I'm doing something wrong with char datatype.

You're replacing each character multiple times. And you're reading past the end of arr1.

Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] as required here. Read that linked article thoroughly (maybe more than once), and update your question accordingly.

I get random symbols or XXXX after compiling -- Compiling successfully only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the code is logically correct.  As you can see, the issue is your code's logic, not the syntax.

@avent Show the input, the expected output and the actual output.

You're aware that doing this with a for loop is terribly inefficient, right?  A direct lookup would be better.

It would be a tremendously useful lesson to try and use the debugger on this program.

There are no dumb questions, but there are questions you need to ask with a LOT of ammunition, and generally the more work you do to arm yourself, the more likely you are to solve the problem yourself. A good question-asking process is also a good debugging process. The best askers don't ask many questions, but the ones they do ask are really weird.

You have two issues with your code. Firstly, if h == 25, then h+1 is 26, and there is no arr1[26]. This is where the "random symbols" are coming from.
The second issue, is that once you've replaced the character, you still check it again, and it finds another match and replaces it, and then rechecks (etc.).
You can change your if statement like so:
if(x[i] == arr1[h]){
     x[i] = arr1[(h + 1) % 26]; // in case h + 1 > 26, loop back to 0 (i.e. 'a')
     break; // don't keep searching for another match
}

You can change how you handle the value when h == 25 however you'd like, I just rolled around to 0 for simplicity.

Or change the array size to 27 and put an additional 'a' in the last position. Then arr1[h+1] always works.

Within the inner for loop
for(int h = 0; h < 26; h++){
    if(x[i] == arr1[h]){
        x[i] = arr1[h + 1];
    }
}

if the letter x[i] is found in the array arr1 at position h then it is changed to the letter arr1[h + 1] due to this statement
x[i] = arr1[h + 1];

So in the next iteration of the for loop (if h + 1 is less than 26) the updated letter is again found and is changed to the next letter in the array arr1. The iterations of the for loop are continued while the condition h < 26 is true. As a result in the last iteration of the for loop the expression arr1[h + 1] accesses memory outside the array arr1 that invokes undefined behavior.
You need to interrupt the inner for loop as soon as a letter that equal to the expression x[i] is found in the array arr1. And if the found letter is 'z' (the last element of the array) you need to assign to the expression x[i] letter 'a' (arr1[0]) instead of the epxression arr1[h+1]
But pay attention to that using the break statement inside loops in general is a bad style of programming. Moreover there is no need to use ordinary for loops introducing auxiliarly variables i and h. For example instead of the outer for loop you could use the range based for loop. Also do not use magic numbers as 26. Using magic numbers in general results in bugs in the program.
At least you could write including header <iterator> the following way
char arr1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                   'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                   'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                   'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                   'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                   'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                   'y', 'z'};

    //...

    for( size_t h = 0; h < std::size( arr1 ); h++){

or the for loop statement can be written also like
    for( size_t h = 0, n = std::size( arr1 ); h < n; h++){

I can suggest the following solution.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const std::string_view lower_case_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    if (std::string s; std::getline( std::cin, s ))
    {
        for (char &c : s)
        {
            auto pos = lower_case_letters.find( c );

            if (pos != std::string_view::npos)
            {
                c = lower_case_letters[ ( pos + 1 ) % std::size( lower_case_letters ) ];
            }
        }

        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
}

The program output might look the following way
abcxyz
bcdyza


Or to handle case sensitivity we can do something like:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);

    for (char &c : x) {  // Iterate through characters by reference
        if (isalpha(c)) {    // Check if the character is a letter
            if (tolower(c) == 'z') {  // Handle 'z' and 'Z'
                c = tolower(c) == 'z' ? 'a' : 'A';
            } else {
                c++; // Shift to the next letter
            }
        }
    }

    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}

Problems solved:

when you reach the letter 'z', arr1[h + 1] tries to access an element
outside the bounds of the array, leading to undefined behavior

You can calculate the shifted character directly. No need for a
nested loop

The code doesn't handle uppercase letters



The code will produce incorrect output if there will be  used the EBCDIC table of characters.
